# MySQL Update statement after adding extra condition at WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL Update statement. It works fine.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1_field1='field1_content', Table1_field2='field2_content'
where Table1_field3=2
```

All the fields above belong to the same table. I then added an extra condition `AND Table2.fieldname='XXX'` to the WHERE clause

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1_fieldname1='field1_content', Table1_fieldname2='field2_content'
where Table1_fieldname3=2 AND Table2.fieldname='XXX'
```

This time, the SQL statement fails. The error is "unknown column `Table2.fieldname` in where clause". However, `Table2.fieldname` does exist.

Comment: What condition do you use to combine `Table1` and `Table2`?

Comment: Read bout UPDATE...JOIN ...

Comment: Table2 ? You might need to join the two tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to use fields from Table2 in your query you'll need use a JOIN between Table1 and Table2.

A JOIN effectively combines a row from each table into a single row for your query, based on a provided condition.
For example if both Table1 and Table2 have a column tableID, we can combine rows from each table where the tableIDs match.
The query would then look like below:

```
UPDATE Table1
JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.tableID = Table2.tableID
SET Table1_fieldname1='field1_content', Table1_fieldname2='field2_content'
WHERE Table1_fieldname3=2 AND Table2.fieldname='XXX';
```

The JOIN keyword is equivalent to INNER JOIN. There are different types of JOINs available and I'd recommend reading up about them.
Here's a reference image to give you an idea of the different types: [image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to join table 1 and table2; then you can update

```
UPDATE Table1 AS b
INNER JOIN Table2 AS g ON b.id = g.id SET Table1_fieldname1='field1_content', Table1_fieldname2='field2_content'
where Table1_fieldname3=2 AND g.fieldname='XXX'
```

Comment: b.id is primary key of Table2 and g.id is primary key of Table1? Will this code still work if id column is not present in the tables?

Comment: no i just added it as example you have to join it using prefer column

Comment: Understand better now. I need to look at the foreign key relationship.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. If you don't mind, I chose the other answer as the answer as it contains more explanations.